# Doing assignments from another function without repeating it

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a class with two functions:

```
class MyClass():
    def function1(self):
        a = 123
        b = 723
        c = 813
        return a + b + c

    def function2(self):
        a = 123
        b = 723
        c = 813
        return a - b - c
```

My question is... Is it possible for **function2** to have the similar **a, b, and c** variables from **function1** without declaring those variables again?

Comment: I think it's ok, variables defined in 1 function are independent from other variables elsewhere, unless `global` is used

Comment: If you are asking how to have the values of variables defined in one function available to other functions in a class, you could look at defining class attributes and assign them to the values of the variables in one function... and then accessing the class attributes in other functions. See [link](https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes)

Answer (score 4):

Given your current code, the variables "*a*", "*b*" and "*c*" will be local to the functions. If you want to input them once and not again, you should give them when you build your object, so provide them to the constructor/builder as inputs.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def function1(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c

    def function2(self):
        return self.a - self.b - self.c


obj = MyClass(5, 3, 2)
print('F1: ', obj.function1())
print('F2: ', obj.function2())
```

Output:

```
F1: 10
F2: 0
```